# Nested If Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

Can anybody help me figure out what am I doing wrong in the given nested If statement formula.

```
IF(COUNT(E2:F2)=0,"",IF(COUNT(E2:F2) =1 AND (F2="")),"",IF(COUNT(E2:F2)=2,E2,"Check")))
```

Comment: And is not done that way it is `AND(crit1,crit2,...)` not `crit1 and crit2`

Comment: So really that second `IF()` is opened and closed without a `true` or `false` result. It literally says `,IF(COUNT(E2:F2) =1 AND (F2=""))` which is meaningless. Probably you are wanting: `IF(COUNT(E2:F2)=0,"",IF(AND(COUNT(E2:F2) =1, (F2="")),"",IF(COUNT(E2:F2)=2,E2,"Check")))`

Comment: Ahh ok, I totally forgot about use of AND. Thanks a lot for fixing it for me. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ScottCraner commented, you probably intended to use the AND function.

Do it this way:

```
AND(condition1,condition2)
```

not

```
condition1 AND condition2 <-BAD
```

Using the adjusted syntax:

```
IF(COUNT(E2:F2)=0,"",IF(AND(COUNT(E2:F2) =1, F2=""),"",IF(COUNT(E2:F2)=2,E2,"Check")))
```

Comment: Alternative formula: `=CHOOSE(COUNT(E2:F2)+1,"",IF(F2="","","Check"),E2)`